# RFHUTIL: can not subscribe to the topic

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to subscribe to the topic via RFHUTIL, but I get an error message: "Queue name required if not managed."
But I do not use queue, I use topic instead. Why should I specify the queue name? How can I subscribe to the topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you subscribe to a topic, messages are sent to you as a result. There are two choices that you can make.

- You can ask for those messages to be sent to a queue
- You can have what is called a "managed subscription" which means you don't have to provide a specific queue name for those messages to be sent to.

First of all, make sure you are using at minimum a V7 RFHUtil. That is when support for MQ V7 Publish/Subscribe was added.

Make sure you are using the PS tab rather than the PubSub tab.

Ensure you select the "Managed Sub" check box.